# Hexadecimal to decimal voltage Conversion

Tags: hex

I want to convert the Hexadecimal values to voltage conversion as mentioned below,

2 Byte Signed 2s Comp Binary Fraction with Binary Point to the right of the most significant bit. 1:512V scaling.
Example :

```
      0x2A80 → 170.00 V 
      0xD580 → ‐170.00 V
```

But the 0x2A80 conversion gives me 10880 decimal value. How can i get 170.00 V from 0x2A80?

Answer (score 1):

If 0x2A80 is 170.00, then that means you have 10 bits before the point and 6 bits after the point. Or in other words, you have 10880/64 == 170.

---

Your question seems to contain a few misconceptions:

1. The fact that 170.0 is a voltage is irrelevant. Numbers work the same no matter whether they are voltages, distances, or just numbers without a unit.
2. In most programming languages, you don't have "decimal" or "hexadecimal" values, you just have values. Decimal and hexadecimal only come in when you're dealing with text output and string. `0x2A80` *is* 10880, and `0xD580` *is* -10880.

---

If you happen to be programming in C:

```
short fixedPointNumber;
float floatingPointNumber;

scanf("%hx", &fixedPointNumber);
floatingPointNumber = fixedPointNumber / 64.0f;
printf("Converted number: %f\n", floatingPointNumber);
```